# Why is Time complexity so irregular in case of this Mergesort program which should be strictly increasing with nlogn graph

Tags: java, sorting

The ouput should be increasing with a graph of nlogn.Why is this time so irregular?

```
for(int j=5000;j<=50000;j=j+5000){
    array = new int[j];
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        array[i] = r.nextInt(10000);
    }

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    mergeSort(array);
    long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("The time taken for" + j + "is" +totalTime );
```

My logic for mergesort is

```
static void mergeSort(int A[])
{
    int n=A.length;
    if(n<2)
        return;
    int m = n/2;
    int leftArray[] = new int[m];
    int rightArray[] = new int[n-m];
    for(int i=0;i<=m-1;i++)
    {
        leftArray[i] = A[i];
    }
    for(int i=m;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        rightArray[i-m] = A[i];
    }
    mergeSort(leftArray);
    mergeSort(rightArray);
    merge(leftArray,rightArray,A);
}
static void merge(int L[],int R[],int A[])
{
    int nL = L.length;
    int nR = R.length;
    int i,j,k;
    i=j=k=0;
    while(i<nL && j<nR)
    {
        if(L[i]>=R[j])
        {
            A[k++] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            A[k++] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    while(i<nL)
    {
        A[k++] = L[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(j<nR)
    {
        A[k++] = R[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

The ouput is in nanoseconds

The time taken for5000 is 1853169

The time taken for10000 is 3428060

The time taken for15000 is 4800190

The time taken for20000 is 3871340

The time taken for25000 is 5546668

The time taken for30000 is 7311482

The time taken for35000 is 7523683

The time taken for40000 is 11520758

The time taken for45000 is 8730432

The time taken for50000 is 9097064

Comment: Because most of the time you are measuring is taken copying arrays.

Comment: But that copying is taking place for every value of j i.e 5000,10000,15000,20000. So for every iteration that copying is done. Why is the time so irregular then. Inc Dec Inc Inc dec

Comment: And every time you split the array you are making another copy.

Comment: Haan correct so the time complexity should increase everytime. Right??? For every new number of data

Comment: But that kind of activity will exercise GC so you are also measuring GC activity.

Comment: GC = Garbage Collector

Comment: Can you please explain in a more simpler way.

Comment: See my answer - hope this clarifies my point.

Comment: Just a thought but what happens if you run this sort in an array where `if(L[i]>=R[j])` is true all of the time? As in all the big numbers in the right side of the original array and all the small ones in the left side.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that most of the time you are measuring is taken by just this section of your code:

```
    int leftArray[] = new int[m];
    int rightArray[] = new int[n-m];
    for(int i=0;i<=m-1;i++)
    {
        leftArray[i] = A[i];
    }
    for(int i=m;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        rightArray[i-m] = A[i];
    }
```

If you can eliminate this section from your timings you are likely to see a more reasonable approximation to your expected figures.

Comment: But this copying thing should be happening for every new value of j. So everytime when j increases the copying should take place. Hence the time should be increased every time for new values of j. I mean strictly increasing. Why is it like increasing and then decreasing then again increasing.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - Because as the amount of memory used and discarded increases, the Java Garbage Collection system has to work harder and do more and therefore take longer.